# how to run project starting without debuging like starting debugging mode?

Tags: winforms, multithreading, visual-c++-2010

i'm using C++ managed 2010 for designing a GUI in a form.h file. The GUI acts as a master querying data streaming from slave card.

Pressing a button a function (in the ApplicationIO.cpp file) is called in which 2 threads are created by using API win32 (CREATETHREAD(...)): the former is for handling data streaming, and the latter is for data parsing and data monitoring on real time grpah on the GUI.

The project has two different behaviour: if it starts in debugging mode it is able to update GUI controls as textbox (using invoke) and graph during data straming, contrariwise when it starts without debugging no data appears in the textbox, and data are shown very slowly on the chart.

has anyone ever addressed a similar problem? Any suggestion, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A pretty classic mistake is to use Control::Begin/Invoke() *too often*.  You'll flood the UI thread with delegate invoke requests.  UI updates tend to be expensive, you can easily get into a state where the message loop doesn't get around to doing its low-priority duties.  Like painting.  This happens easily, invoking more than a thousand times per second is the danger zone, depending on how much time is spent by the delegate targets.

You solve this by sending updates at a realistic rate, one that takes advantage of the ability of the human eye to distinguish them.  At 25 times per second, the updates turn into a blur, updating it any faster is just a waste of cpu cycles.  Which leaves lots of time for the UI thread to do what it needs to do.

This might still not be sufficiently slow when the updates are expensive.  At which point you'll need to skip updates or throttle the worker thread.  Note that Invoke() automatically throttles, BeginInvoke() doesn't.